# How to calculate functional L_2 norm using R

Tags: r

Suppose `f` and `g` are two bounded functions defined on the interval `[0,1]`.

How to calculate the [L_2 distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#Lp_spaces) between `f` and `g`?

Comment: The good site to ask your question is [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I am using R. But I think the referred site is related to mathematica. I don't know how to use it.

Comment: This question in current state is off-topic since it asks for a package. Your task, however, is rather clear and can be formulated as simply "how to calculate L2 function norm", which is quite straightforward by using the definition and `integrate`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expanding my comment:

```
f <- function(x) x^2
g <- function(x) sqrt(cos(x))
z <- function(x) 0

l2_norm <- function(fun) {
  f_sq <- function(x) fun(x)^2
  sqrt(integrate(f = f_sq, lower = 0, upper = 1)$value)
}

l2_dist <- function(f, g) {
  f_diff <- function(x) (f(x) - g(x))^2
  sqrt(integrate(f = f_diff, lower = 0, upper = 1)$value)
}

l2_norm(f) # = sqrt(1/5)
l2_norm(g) # = sqrt(sin(1))
l2_dist(f, z) # = l2_norm(f)
l2_dist(f, g)
```

A similar approach can be used to define e.g. inner product in L2.